# What would be a good idiom in Asciidoc for multiple translations?

Tags: asciidoc, hubpress

I have an article which will have more than one translation, English and Mandarin to start with.  I can use either two documents and have one link the other, or I can have one after the other and add a link to each at the start.

Is there a more elegant way of handling this? e.g. could I choose the language at the start and my choice inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is any other way to do this, at least I know there isn't within asciidoctor (which is what hubpress is using). I do not know if hubpress has anything inpla

Comment: For now, I think I will have two documents and have one link to the other.